# USB TV tuner that works with Windows 10

Tags: laptop, usb, windows

I have Diamond multimedia TV tuner that works with Windows 7, and is supposed to work with Windows 10 but does not. It uses Total media software, when I try to scan for channels it says "not connected or is being used by another app". The device manager shows that it is connected. I've deleted all the games and anything that I thought might be causing the error with no success. Any suggestions as to how to fix it or what tuner would work with Windows 10?